# Conditional to test if post has password protection enabled

Tags: password

I am looking for a conditional to test simply if a post (custom post type, if it somehow makes a difference) is set to have password protection…persistently…regardless of whether user has accessed the post via the password or not.

`post_password_required()` only returns true if the user has not already entered the password

`get_post_status()` (though it *does* return a 'private' status if a post is private) only returns 'published' for a password-protected post

Comment: I think you have to check if `$post->post_password` is not empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
if(!empty($post->post_password)){
   // do some stuff
}
```

which is what the [post_password_required()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L750) code does before checking the user's credentials against the password itself.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't think about looking into the code of that function first!

Comment: That's understandable - the function didn't do what you wanted it to!